# Why is "dentist" preferred to "stomatologist"?

Tags: word-choice

I was using the word ***stomatologist*** because there is an equivalent in my native language, but today in English class I heard this term is rather not used, because the preferred one is ***dentist***.

While this [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=stomatologist%2C%20dentist&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cstomatologist%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdentist%3B%2Cc0) ensures this is true, I wonder why one term is preferred to the other, since both are correct and exist.

Comment: [in English class, for your information]. https://english.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: Did you Google it?  It's a term for a specialty in dentistry.  Few people who are not dentists would be familiar with the word.

Comment: In US English, that word is ... very rare (= never used; do your own Google NGrams). I had no idea what it was, but then with the prompt of dentist all I can think is that it is some one who... I don't know... fills cavities? Dentists (in the US) do a lot more than that.

Comment: Probably for the same reason a student reading jurisprudence would tell most people they were studying law.

Comment: It is not clear what kind of an answer can be expected to a why-question of this sort: it is unlikely that there is any deep reason why English happens to have developed in this way. The fact that English speakers use *dentist* more frequently is not any more in need of an explanation than the fact the speakers of some other languages prefer (some version of) *stomatologist*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was very easy to find the etymology of ***[dentist](https://www.google.com/search?q=etymology%20dentist&safe=strict&sxsrf=ALeKk02kqeHBexYYvTlT1EZqnG46t3hPwQ%3A1623855601195&ei=8RHKYM-_C9Oo8gKd5ISYBw&oq=etymology%20dentist&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyAggAMgYIABAWEB4yBggAEBYQHjIGCAAQFhAeOgcIABBHELADOgQIIxAnOgUIABCRAjoICC4QsQMQgwE6CAgAELEDEIMBOgUIABCxAzoECAAQQzoHCAAQsQMQQzoICAAQsQMQkQI6BwgAEEYQ-QFKBAhBGABQ86IsWLLELGDKyCxoAnACeACAAfIBiAH4DpIBBjE0LjQuMZgBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXrIAQjAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz&ved=0ahUKEwiP_JnCtZzxAhVTlFwKHR0yAXMQ4dUDCA0&uact=5)*** (from French). The etymology of ***[stomatologist](http://www.finedictionary.com/Stomatology.html)*** was not so easy to dig. But as the suffix ***[-(o)logy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/-logy)*** indicates, it is a Greek neologism.

This [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=stomatologist%2Cdentist%2Cstomatology%2Coral+medicine%2C+dentistry&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cstomatologist%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdentist%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cstomatology%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Coral%20medicine%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdentistry%3B%2Cc0) shows that indeed ***dentist*** and ***[dentistry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dentistry)*** are largely more common that ***[stomatologist](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/stomatologist), [stomatology](https://educalingo.com/en/dic-en/stomatologist)*** or ***[oral medicine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oral_medicine)***.

Some distinguish differences between the two terms, saying that stomatology is a larger medical field than dentistry:

> The treatment priorities of dentistry are different from those of stomatology. For example, suppose a patient refers to a dentist to replace a lost premolar tooth. From the dentist’s and the patient’s viewpoints the replacement of that premolar tooth is the first priority; however, from a stomatologist’s viewpoint, determination of the cause of this problem and preservation of the remaining teeth are the first priorities and the second priority is the replacement of the lost premolar tooth. ([read more](https://www.proquest.com/docview/2112243266))

However, another [medical article](https://www.dentaltown.com/Images/Dentaltown/magimages/nov05/DTNov05pg08.pdf) says:

> In  most  of  the  world,  dentists  are  trained  alongside
> physicians and  do  a  specialty  residency  in  stomatology,  the
> medical  study  ofthe mouth and its diseases. The planet has around
> one million den-tists  and  they  are  ***mostly  referred  to  as
> stomatologists***.  Lecturing around  the  world,  it  is  very  apparent
> the  difference  this  training makes  in  how  dentists  in  America
> practice  verses  how  stomatologists practice.

It seems that in English, ***stomatologist*** is mainly used in scientific contexts, and ***dentist*** is so largely used because it is not restricted to scientific context. Even a child understands what a dentist is. This difference may be compared with the [difference](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=doctor%2Cmedical%20practitioner%2Cmedic&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdoctor%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmedical%20practitioner%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmedic%3B%2Cc0) in use of the terms ***doctor, medical practitioner, medic***, which all mean the same. ***Doctor*** is the largely used term, but in scientific literature, words like ***medical practitioner*** and ***medic*** are encountered.

Comment: It would appear that _stomatologist_ is the medical term, common where dental care is integrated with medical care. In he United States, there is very little integration of health care systems of any kind, and none at al for dental care.. Consequently there is no special term for doctors to use, because they call dentists dentists too.

Comment: @JohnLawler: It is so interesting to see how different circumstances shape the use of a term. I searched the [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=stomatologist%2Cdentist%2Cstomatology%2Coral+medicine%2Cdentistry&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=28&smoothing=3) for the American English use of the same terms, and the differences with the [British English](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=stomatologist%2Cdentist%2Cstomatology%2Coral+medicine%2Cdentistry&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=29&smoothing=3) seem to be small.

Comment: @fev. Yes, in Britain they are dentists and registered with the General Dental Council (which also allows them use of the "Doctor" title!) Our dentists are not physicians, but physicians (eg General Practitioners) will often refer patients to dentists with *any* oral problem. In the NHS, determination of cause and preservation of teeth is more important than replacement, and yet our dentists are dentists, and not stomatologists. In fact the root *stoma* conjures up something quite different.

Comment: @AndrewLeach - Indeed. The word immediately suggested the other kind of stoma to me.

Comment: "doctor, medical practitioner, medic" do not mean the same thing. A nurse is a medical practitioner, but isn't a doctor. "Medic" has the connotation of being a battlefield, or otherwise in-the-field, provider of medical care.

Comment: @ Andrew Leach, Kate Bunting Yes, **stoma** can mean something else on its own, but there is no ambiguity about **stomatology** being related to oral medicine and dentistry and not to something else. Accumulation: thank you for the disambiguation. I see the terms are not uniformly [defined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physician) across the web.

Comment: @fev Your edit totally changed the OP's question into another one. You took the wrong lesson from that ngram and from an internet search. 'stomatologist' is very rare to the point of being 'not a word' for most people (and certainly not recognized by most people who go to get help with their teeth. Word recognizability is not a mathematical proof. Somewhere someone may have used 'stoma...' which may make it 'a word', but nobody uses it instead of dentist. Why don't -you- use 'dentist'? Different languages, different cultural history, different words, that's all there is.

Comment: @Mitch "Your edit totally changed the OP's question into another one" - good for me since in the original shape it was closed and now it has got 2 upvotes ;d I had no idea about ngrams, it's great

Comment: @Line OK then. When someone else changes a question so radically, it's not clear that it maintains what you originally expected. So it's good that you confirm that it is appropriate for you. In quite a different direction though is that your original question -and- this modified new one are both... how to say this diplomatically... linguistically naive. These are two different languages and so they treat the words differently. You just don't say 'stomatologist' in English and you just don't say 'dentist' in Russian or whatever.

Comment: If you walk into a dentist in the US and use 'stomatologist' everyone will look at you like you're crazy.